# Find and Replace characters in a string based on two arrays in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have got a String with some special characters.

```
string strValue = "MyString[]{";
```

Here the string strValue contains some special characters and these characters are mentioned in a character array arrFindString and the corresponding character need to be replaced with the character in another character array in arrReplaceString having the same index position.

```
char[] findArray = {'[',']','{'};
char[] replaceArray = { '(', ')', '-' };
```

So in my case the string strValue  has a character called '['.So at first we need to find the corresponding index of that character in findArray then we need to replace that character with the character having the same index in replaceArray .So here '[' has to be replaced by '('

Is there any way the same can be accomplished using linq?...
I know its possible using for each .Please help

Comment: Yes it can be, but the `foreach` is far more natural and will be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq approach

```
string strValue = "MyString[]{"; 
char[] findArray = {'[',']','{'};
char[] replaceArray = { '(', ')', '-' };

Func<char, int, char> GetC = (x, c) => c > -1 ? replaceArray.ElementAt(c) : x;
string Result = string.Concat(strValue.Select(x => GetC(x, Array.IndexOf(findArray, x))));
```

Comment: every answer seems working fine ...and thank you all guys

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd rather combine `findArray` and `replaceArray` into single `Dictionary<Char, Char>`:

```
  Dictionary<Char, Char> replaces = new Dictionary<Char, Char>() {
    {'[', '('},
    {']', ')'},
    {'{', '-'},
  };
```

then you can use *Linq*:

```
  string strValue = "MyString[]{"; 

  String result = new String(strValue
    .Select(c => { 
       Char substitute;

       if (replaces.TryGetValue(c, out substitute))
         return substitute;
       else 
         return c;  
       })
    .ToArray());
```

As an alternative, you can put a *foreach* loop:

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(strValue.Length);

  foreach (var c in strValue) {
    Char substitute;

    if (replaces.TryGetValue(c, out substitute))
      sb.append(substitute);  
    else 
      sb.append(c);   
  }

  String result = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the optimal way. No need to use LINQ here.

```
string strValue = "MyString[]{";
char[] findArray = { '[', ']', '{' };
char[] replaceArray = { '(', ')', '-' };

char[] charsValue = strValue.ToCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < charsValue.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < findArray.Length; j++)
    {
        if (charsValue[i] == findArray[j])
        {
            charsValue[i] = replaceArray[j];
            continue;
        }
    }
}

string newStrValue = new string(charsValue); // MyString()-
```

Comment: Are you sure that `O(m*n)` where `m=charsValue.Length; n=findArray.Length` is a good way to solve this?

Comment: @SerhiyChupryk what makes you think there's a better way?

Comment: This problem should have (intuition) linear solution like the one proposed by Dmitry Bychenko

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-line solution:

```
string strValue = "MyString[]{";
char[] findArray = { '[', ']', '{' };
char[] replaceArray = { '(', ')', '-' };

string newStr = String.Join("", strValue.Select(c => findArray.Contains(c) ? replaceArray[Array.IndexOf(findArray, c)] : c));

Console.WriteLine(newStr); // MyString()-
```